# Google play is asking for Google account

Tags: google-account

My phone (Samsung s3 mini) isn't accepting any Google account: every time I try to enter anything like Googleplay for example it would ask for the Google account. It sais either EXISTING or NEW, and I've tried both of them – none of them worked.

It then says checking account or something, then...couldn't sign in to account.

The same works fine on my other devices.

How can I get that fixed?

Comment: Do you have an active data connection (either cellular or WiFi) when you are trying to sign in?

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing app data and also verify you have either wifi or data connection as Chahk mentioned. Try logging into the proposed Google account in a browser on a computer to verify you have an account & the correct credentials.